# How to compare COUNT of two values in a single column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data something like the below (there are other columns as well like times but for the sake of this question I simplified it):

```
| Runner | Action |
|--------|--------|
| John   | Start  |
| Amy    | Start  |
| Susan  | Start  |
| John   | Finish |
| Amy    | Start  |
| Amy    | Finish |
```

I am trying to get a list of runners with a count of the races they started and a count of the races they finished and show only the racers who didn't finish all the races they started.

Desired output:

```
| Runner | StartCount| FinishCount|
|--------|-----------|------------|
| Amy    |      2    |     1      |
| Susan  |      1    |     0      |
```

To do this I'll need to compare the count of `Action` column against another count of the same column, but I'm not sure if this can be done because you have to add a 'where' clause for the COUNT to work, and there would be two separate WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT Runner, COUNT(Action), * FROM RunnerActions
WHERE Action = 'Start'
```

Is this possible in SQL? What is the process of comparing two separate COUNTs on the same column in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some DBMS, for example MYSQL which you taged as your DBMS, provide the possibility to use conditional sum:

```
SELECT 
Runner, 
SUM(Action = 'Start') AS StartCount,
SUM(Action = 'Finish') AS FinishCount
FROM RunnerActions
GROUP BY
Runner
HAVING 
SUM(Action = 'Start') > 
SUM(Action = 'Finish');
```

This is easy to read and we should prefer this in my opinion.

If we use a DBMS that doesn't provide this option, we can rebuild this logic using `CASE WHEN` to only count the starts as one value and the finishes as another value:

```
SELECT 
Runner, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Start' THEN 1 END) AS StartCount,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Finish' THEN 1 END) AS FinishCount
FROM RunnerActions
GROUP BY
Runner
HAVING 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Start' THEN 1 END) > 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Finish' THEN 1 END);
```

In both queries, we will `GROUP BY` Runner to build the sum per runner.

Finally, in the `HAVING` clause, we will put the condition more starts should appear then finishes.

Both queries will produce the same outcome.

They both will `COUNT` or `SUM` (this makes no difference in our use case) only those rows having the value "Start" as StartCount and only those having the value "Finish" as FinishCount.

If we remove the `HAVING` clause, we will also get those runners who have the same amount of starts and finishes, i.e. for those runners, StartCount and FinishCount will be identic.

If we use the `HAVING` clause, only those runners will be selected that have more starts than finishes.

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zfJNmOkQ)

Comment: Okay I was nowhere close this uses a few things I have not done much of. Thank you so much! Side note: with the COUNT clauses here, does it just assume you're counting the column mentioned in the case?

Comment: @leigero: I edited the answer to explain it more precise, does this help you?